# Bash script to print a text file in color

Tags: bash, text, colors, sed

I have a text file with three paragraphs. I want to display the different paragraphs in different colors using bash script commands. Paragraph 1 in red, paragraph 2 in blue and paragraph 3 in cyan.

I managed to display lines in color using commands like

```
echo -e '\E[32;47m Green.'; tput sgr0
```

However, I want to parse my file and change colors when there is a new paragraph. I would appreciate for some hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The input `/tmp/FILE`** : http://pastie.org/4928415

**The script** :

```
#!/bin/bash

c=1
tput setaf $c
while read a; do
    [[ $a =~ ^$ ]] && tput setaf $((++c))
    echo "$a"
done < /tmp/FILE
tput sgr0
```

**The output** :

[image]

Comment: You just have to modify it a bit to display the wanted colors.

Comment: Thank you so much! can i also convert this colored output to a pdf file with the colors still maintained. thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an awk solution, which uses in turn elements of an array of color settings:

```
BEGIN { nc = split("\33[31;47m \33[34;43m \33[36;40m", colors, " ");
        c=1; print colors[c] }
{ print }
/^$/ { c = 1+(c%nc); print colors[c]}
```

*[Edit:  The above erroneously adds an extra blank line between paragraphs.  Corrected code is as follows:*

```
BEGIN { nc = split("\33[31;47m \33[34;43m \33[36;40m", colors, " ");
        c=1; printf "%s", colors[c] }
/^$/ { c = 1+(c%nc); print colors[c]}
!/^$/
```

*The `!/^$/` causes any non-blank line to print as is. (End Edit)].*

If the above is in file 3-para.awk and data is in file 3-para.data, use a command like `awk -f 3-para.awk 3-para.data` to get output like the following.
[image: screenshot of script output]

For more convenient use, define a function that invokes the script and then resets colors to default:

```
tricolor() {
   awk -f 3-para.awk $1; tput sgr0
}
```

Use the function via (eg) `tricolor 3-para.data`